# Appending data from MongoDB into log files being processed by Logstash and parsed into Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, logstash, elastic-stack

Sorry about the title, my case really couldn't be explained with a single sentence.

Here is my situation:

1. I have a large set of log files (around 4GB) that I wish to parse with Logstash to use with Elastic stack (Logstash, Elasticsearch, Kibana).
2. In the logs, there is a serial number that I have successfully parsed with Logstash. This number corresponds to an index of a MongoDB collection. As each log is being parsed, I want to be able to query the collection with the parsed number and retrieve data which I want to include in the final output that is passed to Elasticsearch.

To make things clearer, here's a rough example. Suppose I have the raw log:

```
2017-11-20 14:24:14.011 123 log_number_one
```

Before the parsed log gets sent to Elasticsearch, I want to query my MongoDB collection with `123`, and get data `data1` and `data2` to append to the document to be sent to Elasticsearch, so my end result will have fields be similar to something like:

```
{ 
    timestamp: 2017-11-20 14:24:14.011, 
    serial: 123, 
    data1: "foo", 
    data2: "bar", 
    log: log_number_one
}
```

An easier way to accomplish this, I assume, would be to simply preprocess the logs and run the numbers through MongoDB before parsing them through Logstash. However, seeing as though I have 4GBs' worth of logfiles, I was hoping for a way to achieve this in one single swoop. I was wondering whether my edge case would be solvable with the ruby filter plugin, where I could possibly run some arbitrary ruby code to do the above?

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Christian_Dahlqvist](https://discuss.elastic.co/u/Christian_Dahlqvist), member of the Elastic Team (all credits to him):

> Depending on the number of records and total size of the data in MongoDB (assuming it is a reasonable size data set), you may be able to extract the data into a file where each serial number is associated with a string representation of the data in JSON form. You could then use the [translate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) to populate a field with the serialised JSON based on the serial number and then use a son filter to parse this and add it to the event.

Reference: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/appending-data-from-mongodb-into-log-files-being-processed-by-logstash-and-parsed-into-elasticsearch/92564/2